# PHP - Use files for multiple sites

Tags: php, include, structure, external

I manage multiple sites with the same structure and i am searching for a way to include some files from the same source to all of them.

Ex: footer, css files.

The websites are built with php using vars declared in other files, so linking, naming and other site specific info won't be a problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at version control systems like Git?

Comment: @Sherlock Tacking on to this, that you could keep the common info in it's own repo and pull that into the projects.  Keeping the common info repo would be trivial with a cron job or something similar.

Or if you felt inclined, you could probably put some of it on a CDN.

Comment: Are the sites stored on the same server?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a common include path (outside the document root) for all the files that you need to share between sites, and include the files from each of your sites that way: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

eg if you set the include_path to have /var/www/lib and put your footer.php in there, then you can

```
include('footer.php');
```

in each of your sites and they will all use the footer from /var/www/lib/footer.php

one thing to watch is for css / js and img files - they need to be served from the document root, so you can only use this technique for php files.

[you may have to watch out for your open_basedir too]

Comment: You can also use `include('http://another-domain.com/common-includes/footer.php');` if not on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I understand what you are asking for but I did this multiple times and it works.

1. put all files you use (css headers,footers, etc) in the same root directory
2. at the top of your PHP files write **include 'filename.php;** (or .css, .html , whatever extension they have)